# Error "Client.NetworkInterfaceLimitExceeded" in AWS Lambda API Calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-vpc, chalice

**Background:**

I have 2 web services implemented through Chalice framework on AWS lambda. Both framework points to the same RDS (MySQL) database backend.

**Problem:**

User can't login to apps these two days in the afternoon for a few hours. (Those who has login will be logout).

Each API call creates a "CreateNetworkInterface" event in CloudTrail. Many API calls ended up with Error code "Client.NetworkInterfaceLimitExceeded". How can I increase the limit?

**Clue** 
In "[5 Things you should know before using Lambda](https://blog.axilis.com/5-things-you-should-know-before-using-lambda-bf4cf1c9d917)" by Sergej Jakovljev, he mentioned about limitation in Using Amazon RDS with Lambda (point 2). I use VPN of 4 subnets (2 public & 2 private). The RDS is in the 2 subnets. What are the specific steps to increase ENI points?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like our Lambda functions did not delete network interface after creation. Used a script to clean up ENI created by lambda functions. https://github.com/qinjie/learn-aws/blob/master/aws-clean-lambda-eni.js. But here is another question, I have cleaned 347 ENI from that VPC. There are still 3 ENI used by RDS etc which cannot be removed. How can max ENI be 350 only? My subnet allows more than 10k IP address. Anyone can help to explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

350 is the documented default limit for elastic network interfaces.  You will need to submit a request to increase the limit.

> Network interfaces per region 350
>
> This limit is the greater of either the default limit (350) or your On-Demand Instance limit multiplied by 5. The default limit for On-Demand Instances is 20. If your On-Demand Instance limit is below 70, the default limit of 350 applies. To increase this limit, submit a request or increase your On-Demand Instance limit.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_vpc

Comment: Thanks Michael. It's documented here too. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Appendix_Limits.html